# Retrieve packages and functions used in a Session

Tags: r

Is there a way to get a list of packages and functions that were used during a R session ?
Not loaded packages, but the list of functions(with the info on the package name) that were actually used in the code that was run in the R console.

This would help to clean up the code from some scripts, were test different packages and forget to delete the ones not used anymore. Also to check which function from what package we use, instead of checking each function in the code one by one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The session "log" can be saved as a text file using the code provided in `help(history)`:

```
.Last <- function()
    if(interactive()) try(savehistory("~/.Rhistory"))
```

You could process this text file with R by first accessing with readLines and then extracting with regular expressions. If you also want to capture the loaded packages this will give you a character vector of package names:

```
> names(c(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs, sessionInfo()$loadedOnly))
[1] "timereg"  "survival" "sos"      "brew"     "lattice"  "grid"     "tools"
```

That could be added to the .Last function defined above. The details of how to do this will depend on your goals which at the moment see somewhat vague.